# Invoke rest api from c#

Tags: rest-api, magento-2.1.3, c#

I am successfully getting `access token`, but when I call customer service it is throwing error.

> Error:Bad Request/Unauthorized

for this I have tried below code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{


    class Program
    {

        private const string URL = "http://192.168.0.52/magento214/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token";
        private const string URL1 = "http://192.168.0.52/magento214/index.php/rest/V1/customers/";
        private const string DATA = @"{""username"": ""admin"",""password"": ""pass@word1""}";
        private const string DATA1 = @"{""id"": ""1""}";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                AddComponent();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static void AddComponent()
        {

            try
            {
                System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
                //client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(URL);
                byte[] cred = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:password");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Convert.ToBase64String(cred));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = new StringContent(DATA, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage messge = client.PostAsync(URL, content).Result;
                string description = string.Empty;
                if (messge.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    description = result;
                    AddComponent1(description);
                }
                else
                {
                    string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    description = result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static void AddComponent1(string key)
        {

            try
            {
                var rowString = key.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
                System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
                //client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(URL);
                byte[] cred = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rowString);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Convert.ToBase64String(cred));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = new StringContent(DATA1, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage messge = client.PostAsync(URL1, content).Result;
                string description = string.Empty;
                if (messge.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    description = result;
                    getCustomerList(description);
                }
                else
                {
                    string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    description = result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

}
```

Any help on this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because , its a c# code

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala not a off-topic, here I am invoking magento 2 `rest` api.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because essentially this is a question about how to connect to ANY API in c#, not specifically about certain Magento API features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your `AddComponent1(string key)` method

```
private static void AddComponent1(string key)
        {

            try
            {
                var rowString = key.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
                System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
                //client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(URL);
                byte[] cred = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rowString);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Convert.ToBase64String(cred));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = new StringContent(DATA1, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage messge = client.PostAsync(URL1, content).Result;
                string description = string.Empty;
                if (messge.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    description = result;
                    getCustomerList(description);
                }
                else
                {
                    string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    description = result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

to

```
public static void AddComponent1(string key)  
        {
            var rowString = key.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
            Uri geturi = new Uri("http://192.168.0.52/bcw214/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1"); //replace your url  
            System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", rowString);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage messge = client.GetAsync(geturi, 0).Result;
            if (messge.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            else
            {
                string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
```

it will work. Please let me know if it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

To answer a bit more generally:

You were `POST`-ing data when you should `GET` it. `POST` or `PUT` should only be used when you intend to *change* the data on the server. For just reading existing data, you should only ever use `GET`requests. This is a basic tenet of REST.